# Bunifumetrotextbox in VB.net

Tags: bunifu

I want to set a bunifumetrotextbox to readonly but I get an error stated

> ‘readonly’ is not a member of ‘Bunifumetrotextbox ‘

I really need to set this textbox to readonly. Can anyone help me

Comment: Tried `ReadOnly` ?

Comment: @John3136 yes please

Comment: @user8386217: What is a "Bunifumetrotextbox"? Never heard that before, what do I miss?

Comment: @nabuchodonossor It is a type of framework in visual studio. It gives the toolbox a cool and exciting feature

Comment: @user8386217: thank you 4 info, the controls have a nice look. maybe there is a 'Active' property, or a 'Editable' property. It has not to be named 'ReadOnly' as with the standard textbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know that it is a bit late for the answer but if it works for someone else I use this:

TEXTBOXBUNIFU.Enabled = False

The disadvantage is that the text makes it gray and not in the original color that you put it in the textbox settings.